# org/jetbrains/kotlin/android/synthetic/idea/AndroidExtensions Gradle Model : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I am using the following setup:

- Just updated Intellij to 2019.1.1
- I converted my gradle project to use gradlew (ran `$ gradle wrapper` to generate gradlew in my root project)
- Using Java 7
- Then run/import the project in intellij to automatically detect it as a project

My IntelliJ is getting the error (in IntelliJ only):

> org/jetbrains/kotlin/android/synthetic/idea/AndroidExtensions Gradle
>   Model : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

But when I run the `$ gradlew clean build` in command line, it ran and build successfully

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I disabled kotlin plugin of IntelliJ since I am not using it, it is just preventing me to build the project in IntelliJ.

Go to File > Settings > Plugins > Search 'kotlin':
[image]

After this, IntelliJ will restart. And your project will now be detected as gradle project